# How to extract token information from attribute "elements"?

Tags: antlr3

**1. Overall Task:**

I want to customize the Java.stg to modify the token display format in the comment of the code block for an alternative of grammar rule.

**2. Context:**

one rule in my current grammar is:

```
temporal returns [String ret]:

  NEXT disj
  {$ret= $ret= "X ".concat($disj.ret);}

  | EVENTUALLY disj

  {$ret= "F ".concat($disj.ret);}`

;
```

The corresponding generated code block (in parser) is as follows:

```
switch (alt2) {

            case 1 :
                // RERS.g:26:7: NEXT disj
                {
                match(input,NEXT,FOLLOW_NEXT_in_temporal204); 

                pushFollow(FOLLOW_disj_in_temporal206);
                disj2=disj();

                state._fsp--;


                ret = ret = "X ".concat(disj2);

                }
                break;
            case 2 :
                // RERS.g:28:7: EVENTUALLY disj
                {
                match(input,EVENTUALLY,FOLLOW_EVENTUALLY_in_temporal222); 

                pushFollow(FOLLOW_disj_in_temporal224);
                disj3=disj();

                state._fsp--;


                ret = "F ".concat(disj3);

                }
                break;
```

**3. My Goal:**

Change the comment from format like `// RERS.g:26:7: NEXT disj` to `NEXT_disj`, i.e., from `<fileName>:<description>` to `<MyOwnAttribute>`

**4. Attempt so far:**

I tried to modify the template "alt(elements,altNum,description,autoAST,outerAlt,treeLevel,rew)" as follows:

```
alt(elements,altNum,description,autoAST,outerAlt,treeLevel,rew) ::= <<
/* <elements:ExtractToken()> */
{
<@declarations()>
<elements:element()>  // as I understand, it's just an template expansion to apply the sub templates in each elements
<rew>
<@cleanup()>
}
>>
```

I checked that in this context, the value of attribute elements is something like `{el=/tokenRef(), line=26, pos=7}{el=/ruleRef(), line=26, pos=12}{el=/execAction(), line=27, pos=7}`.
I think I should "overload" the "tokenRef" template to spit out tokens formatted like "NEXT_disj"

**5. Questions:**

1. How to "overload" an existing template? I want to do that because I will have to modify the value of "elements" otherwise.
2. How can I only apply a template to a specific element in attribute "elements", instead of applying it to every element (like what template "element()" does)?
3. I think there should be some convenient way to achieve my goal. Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.